# Tuning parameters with caret

Tags: r, r-caret

Im using the caret package in R to build a regression model using a Cubist model tree, which has two tuning parameters:

Tuning Parameters: committees (#Committees), neighbors (#Instances)

I think I am trying to implement the tuning parameters incorrectly and need some help to fix the issue. Following the examples on the caret site I have built a grid for my tuning parameters as follows:

```
cubistGrid <- expand.grid(committees = 30, neighbors = 10)
```

then Im calling the grid using the train function as follows:

```
LMFit1 <- train(Total~., data = training, method = "cubist", trControl = fitControl, tuneGrid = cubistGrid)
```

Im getting the following error:

```
Something is wrong; all the RMSE metric values are missing:
```

I dont have any issues with my dataframe as Ive run many models on it to date; this is the first time Ive used the tuning parameters.

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: The document by Max Kuhn on [Cubist Models For Regression](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Cubist/vignettes/cubist.pdf) will be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, not a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), but if you check the warnings you will see the following:

> predictions failed for Resample1: committees=30, neighbors=10 Error in
>   predict.cubist(modelFit, newdata, neighbors =
>   modelFit$tuneValue$neighbors) :    'neighbors' must be less than 10

Set the neighbors to a value less than 10.  That should take care of the empty rmse metrics.

Comment: After a similar issue and ultimately reading the cubist documentation, neighbors must be an integer between 0 and 9.  It would be good if the train function checked the inputs and reported this.